# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent. C# popup close

Tags: c#, javascript, popup

I am trying to refesh parent page of popup page using java script from popup page.But I am getting error like this:

Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.

my Javascript is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function proceed() {
        opener.location.reload(true);

    }
</script> 

 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn" OnClientClick ="proceed()" Width ="140px" runat="server" Text="Submit"   onclick="btnSubmit_Click" style="height: 26px" 

                ValidationGroup="acs54321" />
```

I am getting this error on this line of javascript file for popup:

```
 string output = sb.ToString();

 byte[] s = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);
  page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", s.Length.ToString());   <----Error on this line
```

Comment: Try adding the header in your JS like `header('My-Header: I am a header');`

Comment: Post a bigger part of your C# code - especially what you do *before* the part you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page has already been sent down to the browser, you can't add more to it's header.

Comment: STL then wt is the solution for this.

Comment: It must be sent from the host with the `<head>` and finalized before the `<body>`.

Comment: could you provide me code sample of how to do it as I dont have any idea regarding this.

Comment: Sorry, I can't.  You can't modify the HTML header that was sent down to the browser once it was complete.  I do not believe what you're attempting to do can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Client event run first, so headers headers have been sent when server evetnt occurs.